Issue with relative paths in data.yaml file when trying to train yolo custom model
I am trying to create a training pipeline to train a custom yolov9 model with user inputted labeled images.
I am having an issue where if I make my data.yaml file use relative paths, I get the error:
RuntimeError: Dataset 'OIT_model/customOIT/customdatasetyolo/data.yaml' error
Dataset 'OIT_model/customOIT/customdatasetyolo/data.yaml' images not found , missing path 'C:\GitHub\Anomaly_detection_combine\OIT_model\Anomaly_detection_combine\OIT_model\customOIT\customdatasetyolo\Anomaly_detection_combine\OIT_model\customOIT\customdatasetyolo\val'

What is even more odd, is that the path the error mentions,
'C:\\GitHub\\Anomaly_detection_combine\\OIT_model\\Anomaly_detection_combine\\OIT_model\\customOIT\\customdatasetyolo\\Anomaly_detection_combine\\OIT_model\\customOIT\\customdatasetyolo\\val'

is not a path that exists or is being requested anywhere. The actual path is
'C:\\GitHub\\Anomaly_detection_combine\\OIT_model\\customOIT\\customdatasetyolo\\val'

for some reason it is repeating the first part of the path 3 times.
This is the data.yaml file:
path: OIT_model/customOIT/customdatasetyolo
train: OIT_model/customOIT/customdatasetyolo/train
val: OIT_model/customOIT/customdatasetyolo/val
nc: 1
names: ['5']

and this is the code that is starting training:
def train_custom_dataset_yolo(data_path, epochs=100, imgsz=64, verbose=True):
    model = YOLO("OIT_model/yolov9c.pt")
    # Specify the save directory for training runs
    save_dir = 'OIT_model/customOIT/yolocustomtrainoutput'
    if os.path.exists(save_dir):
        for file in os.listdir(save_dir):
            file_path = os.path.join(save_dir, file)
            if os.path.isfile(file_path) or os.path.islink(file_path):
                os.unlink(file_path)
            elif os.path.isdir(file_path):
                shutil.rmtree(file_path)
    os.makedirs(save_dir, exist_ok=True)
    model.train(data=data_path, epochs=epochs, imgsz=imgsz, verbose=verbose, save_dir=save_dir)
    return
train_custom_dataset_yolo('OIT_model/customOIT/customdatasetyolo/data.yaml', epochs=1,imgsz=64, verbose=True)

Very strangely however, when I replace the relative paths with absolute paths, like so:
path: C:/GitHub/fix/Anomaly_detection_combine/OIT_model/customOIT/customdatasetyolo
train: C:/GitHub/fix/Anomaly_detection_combine/OIT_model/customOIT/customdatasetyolo/train
val: C:/GitHub/fix/Anomaly_detection_combine/OIT_model/customOIT/customdatasetyolo/val
nc: 1
names: ['5']

training works without issue. Using absolute pathing is not an option for me, as this application needs to be reproductible on others machines.

Try this content for the data.yaml file:
path: OIT_model/customOIT/customdatasetyolo
train: train
val: val
nc: 1
names: ['5']

The train and val paths should be relative to the dataset root dir  path, so for instance, the full train path will be like os.path.join(path, train). Example for object detection task dataset.yaml: https://docs.ultralytics.com/datasets/detect/#supported-dataset-formats

This unfortunately did not help, I still get the same error:
RuntimeError: Dataset 'OIT_model/customOIT/customdatasetyolo/data.yaml' error
Dataset 'OIT_model/customOIT/customdatasetyolo/data.yaml' images not found , missing path 'C:\GitHub\fix\Anomaly_detection_combine\OIT_model\customOIT\customdatasetyolo\OIT_model\customOIT\customdatasetyolo\val'
Note dataset download directory is 'OIT_model\customOIT\customdatasetyolo'. You can update this in 'C:\Users\SESA775098\AppData\Roaming\Ultralytics\settings.json'

